# Heroku- Could not find paperclip-3.1.3 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

This morning when I tried to update my website, heroku didn't let me push the app. 
Here's the message I got.

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
   Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
   Fetching git://github.com/drhenner/nifty-generators.git
   Could not find paperclip-3.1.3 in any of the sources
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
!     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I don't have paperclip- 3.1.3 in my gem file. I'm not sure why it's looking for paperclip 3.1.3
Here's my gem file

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.6'
gem 'asset_sync'
group :assets do
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.2.3"

gem "activemerchant",  '~> 1.17.0' #, :lib => 'active_merchant'
gem 'authlogic', "3.0.3"
gem 'bluecloth',     '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'cancan', '~> 1.6.7'
gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.rc.0'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'dalli', '~> 1.1.5'

gem "friendly_id", "~> 3.3"
gem 'haml',  ">= 3.0.13"#, ">= 3.0.4"#, "2.2.21"#,
gem "jquery-rails"

gem 'aws-sdk'

group :production do
  gem  'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end

gem 'nested_set', '~> 1.6.3'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.5.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.0'
gem 'prawn', '~> 0.12.0'

gem 'rails3-generators', '~> 0.17.0'
gem 'rmagick',    :require => 'RMagick'

gem 'rake', '~> 0.9.2'
gem 'state_machine', '~> 1.1.2'

gem 'sunspot_solr'
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 1.3.0rc'

gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'dynamic_form'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'

  gem "autotest-rails-pure"

  gem "rails-erd"
  gem "ruby-debug19"

end
group :test, :development do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 2.8.0"
  gem 'capybara', :git => 'git://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.git'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl', "~> 3.3.0"
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', "~> 3.3.0"
  gem 'mocha', '~> 0.10.0', :require => false
  gem 'rspec-rails-mocha'
  gem "rspec",        "~> 2.8.0"
  gem "rspec-core",         "~> 2.8.0"
  gem "rspec-expectations", "~> 2.8.0"
  gem "rspec-mocks",        "~> 2.8.0"
  gem 'email_spec'
  gem "faker"
  gem "autotest", '~> 4.4.6'
  gem "autotest-rails-pure"
  gem "autotest-growl"
  gem "ZenTest", '4.6.2'

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 3.1.3 of Paperclip was "yanked" for some reason. You can see this on the [RubyGems page for that version](http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip/versions/3.1.3). Obviously your Gemfile was bundled during the brief period this Gem was available.

Version 3.1.4 was it's immediate replacement, if you do not wish to upgrade to the latest version (3.3.1).

To use this you should update your Gemfile to read:

```
gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.1.4'
```

Run `bundle update paperclip` after editing the Gemfile.

> "I don't have paperclip- 3.1.3 in my gem file. I'm not sure why it's looking for paperclip 3.1.3"

`~>3.0` is like saying `>=3.0` and `<4.0`. Hence 3.1.3 is valid. The relevant documentation is available on the [Bundler website](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/gemfile.html).

Comment: Paperclip 3.13 is not on my gem list, neither is it in my gemfile. And I added gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.1.4' in my gemfile. But did heroku still look for 3.1.3.

Comment: You need to do the `bundle update paperclip`. This should change the paperclip version in your Gemfile.lock file. Commit this, then push it to Heroku.