# "Could not find bootstrap-sass-2.3.1.1 in any of the sources" on Heroku push

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, bundle, bundler

I am trying to deploy to Heroku (rails 3 app) and keep getting this error:

```
 Checking in `vendor/bundle` is not supported. Please remove this directory
       and add it to your .gitignore. To vendor your gems with Bundler, use
       `bundle pack` instead.
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Could not find bootstrap-sass-2.3.1.1 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app
```

I have looked at many of the other "Could not find [gem] in any of the sources" posts, like:

[Heroku- Could not find paperclip-3.1.3 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664572/heroku-could-not-find-paperclip-3-1-3-in-any-of-the-sources)
[Heroku: Could not find libv8-3.15.11.1 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985498/heroku-could-not-find-libv8-3-15-11-1-in-any-of-the-sources)
[Could not find multi_json-1.7.2 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578144/could-not-find-multi-json-1-7-2-in-any-of-the-sources)

and tried all of the solutions they propose, and am still getting this.

My gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~> 3.2.11'

group :production, :staging do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem 'rails-footnotes', '>= 3.7.5.rc4'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem "less-rails"
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.0"
gem 'thin'
gem 'rails_admin'
gem 'devise'
gem 'binding_of_caller'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'twitter'
```

Thanks in advance for any support you can provide.

Also:

I ran

bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin --deployment

in Terminal as that is what Heroku wants to run to see what would happen. And apparently once you run it, it saves all of the options you set, so now when I run "dundle install", it uses all of those options. Any idea how I roll back to default options?

**EDIT**

The answer to the second part is rm -rf .bundle && bundle install

**EDIT 2**

It's clearly something with my particular gemfile. I replaced my gemfile with the one from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268771/rake-aborted-couldnt-find-file-twitter-bootstrap) thread, and it deployed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a bug in the bootstrap-sass gem itself.

https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass/commit/abf20dae81b894fc5e03aaa006887265254277d1

I set the following:

```
gem "bootstrap-sass", "2.3.1.0"
```

then ran

```
gem uninstall bootstrap-sass
bundle update bootstrap-sass
bundle install
```

And was able to push to heroku again.

Comment: Thank you! Also, it was "rails-admin" pulling this gem along with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried explicitly requiring bootstrap-sass in your gem file?

```
gem "bootstrap-sass", "2.3.1.1"
```

Comment: looked at other posts like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268771/rake-aborted-couldnt-find-file-twitter-bootstrap) that even reference the same gem, followed the instructions and am getting same error

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was due to the fact that the bootstrap-sass gem was in the assets group.

I removed it from the assets-group and it worked fine in Heroku